# Create a link to My Items on the launchpad

Tags: content-editor, launchpad

I know how to create a custom launchpad button, but I'd like to make one that links to the content editor with a view of My Items displayed (maybe even maximized).  It looks like this is a JS call within the content editor, so I'm wondering if it's possible at all to access as a standard link property of a launchpad button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to switch to core database .

You need to add a new MyItems LauchPad Button under:

**/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/ContentEditing/**

You have to set the link field value to :

**/sitecore/shell/-/xaml/Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Dialogs.LockedItems.aspx**

[image]